# Admin SDK: updateUser with providerData

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Is possible to use **updateUser()** with add more providers in **providerData** property by admin sdk?
I want to implement link accounts feature in restful service.

Answer (score 0):

Linking of accounts isn't a feature of the Admin SDK as [listed in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).  You'll need to [do that from your client app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking).  But you could always [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features), but I imagine that the feature is designed so that the end user should be able to choose if they want accounts to be linked.